# Resizable jQuery UI tools not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make floating text into DIV. so i make below code but i want to make resizable Div. Here show my code please any one suggest me why .resizable() not working here ?

I want to make resize main class div and when i resize class=main div than class="divs" contains text shouls also be floating and overflow text should goes into another div.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Floating_Text In div</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- // <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script type="http://batiste.dosimple.ch/blog/posts/2008-05-18-1/jquery.drag.resize.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp">
<div ng-controller="Myctrl">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="alldiv">
            <div id="cls1" class="divs"></div>
            <div id="cls2" class="divs"></div>
            <div id="cls3" class="divs"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var app = angular.module('MyApp',[]);

    app.controller('Myctrl' , function ($scope, $http) {

        $http.get('text.json').success(function(data1, status, headers, config) {
            var data = data1.text;
            data = decodeURIComponent(data);
            var currentCol = $('.divs:first');
            var wordArray=data.split(' ');



            $.fn.hasOverflow = function() {
               var div= document.getElementById($(this).attr('id'));
               if(div){
                    return div.scrollHeight>div.clientHeight;   
               }

            };
            for(var x=0; x<wordArray.length; x++){
                var word= wordArray[x];
                currentCol.append(word+' ');
                if (currentCol.hasOverflow()){
                    currentCol = currentCol.next('.divs');
                }
            }
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log(config)
        });
        $scope.$apply();

        $(".main").resizable();
    });


  </script>
  </html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console errors?

Comment: Move your script **before** the `</body>` tag, otherwise it doesn't get evaluated

Comment: @devqon Yes checked console their are not any kind of error display

Comment: @GunjanPatel create a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) with your code

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/higunjan/fcrcxawd/1/

now Angular does not call from ng-click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. add the following style css into your code
2. put your js code into following:

   $(function(){

   ```
   // your js code
   ```

   });